# Test HTTPClient Angular 4 "Expected undefined to be defined"

Tags: angular, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

Testing Angular 4 HTTPClient

Following this [post](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/new-httpclient-angular-4-3-x-drys-network-calls-testing/)

In the service

```
 getBlogs(){
     return this._http.get(this.blogsURL+'blogs')
          .map((result: Response ) => {
               this.blogs  = result['blogs'];
               return this.blogs;
     })
 }
```

And then the test:
I started off injecting the service and HttpTestingController into the it block but putting it into the before each works just as well.

The problem occurs when request.flush is called and so fires the subscribe method, they're are no results returned

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { BlogsService } from './blogs.service';
import { Blog } from '../models/blog';


describe('BlogsService', () => {
  let service:BlogsService;
  let blogsURL:string;
  let httpMock:HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [BlogsService],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(BlogsService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    blogsURL = 'http://localhost:3000/'
  });



 it('#getBlogs should return data',() => {
   service
       .getBlogs()
       .subscribe(result => {
         expect(result).toBeDefined();
         expect(result.length).toBe(2);
         expect(result).toEqual([
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Foo',
            numSales: 100
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bar',
            numSales: 200
          }
        ]);
       });


     // look up our request and access it
     const request = httpMock.expectOne(blogsURL+'blogs');
     // verify it is a GET
     expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');

     // Now, provide the answer to the caller above,
     // flushing the data down the pipe to the caller and
     // triggering the test's subscribe method
     request.flush([
          {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Foo',
            numSales: 100
          }, {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Bar',
            numSales: 200
          }
        ]);
     //
    //  // make sure it actually got processed...
     httpMock.verify();
   });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trial and error (mostly error)

I've solved this and I think gained a better understanding of testing the HTTPClient.

Lets start with what's being returned from the database server

```
{message: 'Success', blogs: blogs}
```

A json object with a message and my array of blogs called blogs

Next the function in the service called getBlogs

The 2 important lines are:

```
  this.blogs  = res['blogs'];
  return this.blogs;
```

what this does is extract the blogs array from the results, adds to the var this.blogs and then returns it.

The thing I keep forgetting is that, I am testing the actual function in my service and not a separate entity, hence the test needs blogs
to be returned, which is why I was getting an undefined error, so I added a mock blogs array:

```
  blogs = [{_id: '1234',title: 'title1-test', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk', script:'Some test script'}, {_id: '12345',title: 'title2', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk', script:'Some test script2'}];
```

And then in the flush statement

```
request.flush({message:"Success", blogs:blogs});
```

Because this needs to emulate what's returned from the server, so the code can extract it.

Complete code:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { BlogsService } from './blogs.service';
import { Blog } from '../models/blog';


describe('BlogsService', () => {
  let service:BlogsService;
  let blogsURL:string;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let blogs:Blog[];

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [BlogsService],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(BlogsService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    blogsURL = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    blogs = [{_id: '1234',title: 'title1-test', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk', script:'Some test script'}, {_id: '12345',title: 'title2', vidUrl: 'XpiipWULkXk', script:'Some test script2'}];

  });


  it('#getBlogs should return data',() => {
    service
        .getBlogs()
        .subscribe(results => {
          expect(results).toBeDefined();
          //has to be what is returned by the function
          expect(results).toEqual(blogs);
          console.log(results)

        });
      // look up our request and access it
      const request = httpMock.expectOne(blogsURL+'blogs');
      // verify it is a GET
      expect(request.request.method).toEqual('GET');

      request.flush({message:"Success", blogs:blogs});
     //  // make sure it actually got processed...
      httpMock.verify();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data correctly returned from your url, you seem to be forgetting `result.json()` in `map` function inside your service. Angular http service returns an object `Response` and you need to call it’s `json` function to get your actual json object then you can return your data. Change your `getBlogs` method to the following

```
 getBlogs(){
     return this._http.get(this.blogsURL+'blogs')
      .map((result: Response ) => {
           const resp = result.json();
           this.blogs  = resp['blogs'];
           return this.blogs;
      })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I'm using HTTPClient Angular 4 that doesn't need to do that

Comment: Well when I saw your `this._http` I thought you were using Http service.